# Why are there missing numbers in scrum poker (i.e. 4,6,...)?

Tags: scrum

We are in the process of planning our first sprint using scrum poker cards and we were wondering,

why are there missing numbers in scrum poker (i.e. 4,6,...)?

Comment: @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362286/why-is-the-fibonacci-series-used-in-agile-planning-poker

Comment: It's easier to decide for small stories if it's a 5 or an 8. But for larger stories it does not make sense to choose between a 40 or a 45. In this dimensions your estimations cannot be that precise

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (You can also flag for moderator intervention to have this question migrated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One commercially available set of Scrum poker cards use a sequence ***similar*** to the Fibonacci sequence:

> 0, ½, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 20, 40, 100, and optionally a ? (unsure) and
>   a coffee cup (I need a break)

As for why, it's to emphasise that difficulty does not increase linearly, it usually increases exponentially (hence the approximation of Fibonacci sequence).

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9362286/203371) post for other ideas as to the choice of this sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of numbers used for prioritizing in Scrum is a Fibonacci sequence. The reason the Fibonacci sequence is that experience shows that the sequence tends to be accurate for the way that people estimate difficulty/level of effort.